# Question regarding HEX editor and retrieving file content from raw format

Tags: digital, computer-forensics

How to view the content of a file in raw format in hex editor? and how to find the header offset and tailer offset of a document in raw format in hex editor?

Answer (score 0):

*1. How to view the content of a file in raw format in hex editor?*
On Linux / Mac you can use xxd, which also has a lot of formatting options of the output, but a simple example:

```
xxd file.pdf | less
00000000: 2550 4446 2d31 2e37 0d25 e2e3 cfd3 0d0a  %PDF-1.7.%......
00000010: 3131 3837 3420 3020 6f62 6a0d 3c3c 2f4c  11874 0 obj.<</L
00000020: 696e 6561 7269 7a65 6420 312f 4c20 3330  inearized 1/L 30
00000030: 3934 3237 392f 4f20 3131 3837 372f 4520  94279/O 11877/E
00000040: 3133 3334 3538 2f4e 2037 362f 5420 3238  133458/N 76/T 28
00000050: 3536 3638 312f 4820 5b20 3136 3733 2034  56681/H [ 1673 4
00000060: 3331 315d 3e3e 0d65 6e64 6f62 6a0d 2020  311]>>.endobj.
...

...
002f36c0: 4134 3534 3437 3444 4434 3337 3e3c 3036  A454474DD437><06
002f36d0: 3839 3542 4133 4234 4341 3434 3044 4232  895BA3B4CA440DB2
002f36e0: 3435 3937 3645 3545 3331 3231 3738 3e5d  45976E5E312178>]
002f36f0: 3e3e 0d73 7461 7274 7872 6566 0d31 3136  >>.startxref.116
002f3700: 0d25 2545 4f46 0d                        .%%EOF.
```

You can also open any file using popular hex editor HxD on Windows ( screenshot from https://mh-nexus.de/en/graphics/HxDShotLarge.png )

[image: HxD]

*2. how to find the header offset and tailer offset*

Let's take a look at [file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) and magic bytes. As you can see, the lenght of them can differ:

```
1F 9D           ..     0    z tar.z     compressed file (often tar zip) using Lempel-Ziv-Welch algorithm 
25 50 44 46 2d  %PDF-  0    pdf     PDF document[16]
ed ab ee db     í«îÛ   0    rpm     RedHat Package Manager (RPM) package [3]
```

If you don't want to manually inspect based on the previous list, but rather programatically identify file signatures, there are some libraries for different languages, such as [pyfsig](https://github.com/schlerp/pyfsig), and they maintain a list of current file signatures under [current list](https://github.com/schlerp/pyfsig#current-list) that they can deal with.